# How to make rounded border-image in CSS?

Tags: css

I want to create a rounded image profile with linear-gradient color.

My current HTML:

```html
<img src="/images/profile.webp" alt="" class="card-header-user-profile"/>
```

My current CSS:

```css
.card-header-user-profile {
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-image: linear-gradient(45deg, green, red) 1;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

My current result:

[image]

I want to make the border: linear-gradient + rounded.

How can I do this in CSS?

Comment: Please include your HTML as well.

Comment: @InSync, I added my HTML code.

Comment: Note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took some experimenting, but I think this:

```css
.card-header-user-profile {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, green, red);
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/edd8ed/080808" alt="" class="card-header-user-profile"/>
```

should work properly. I set the background to be the gradient instead of the border and then added some padding. You can change the thickness of the border by adjusting the padding.

Comment: Perfect. SImple. No additional wrappers. Cross-browser. Thank you.

Comment: Please fix your code snippet.

Answer (score -1):

Would something like this work? You may have to adjust some of the colors, positioning to get it to your exact liking.

```css
.card-header-user-profile {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(45deg, green, red) 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), radial-gradient(circle at bottom left, green, red);
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
}
```

```html
<img class="card-header-user-profile" src="https://place-hold.it/80">
```

Comment: When I change the `border-image` value to 0, it works on Mozilla but it does not work on chrome.